Updating SentOn Date value in .msg file saved in local folder
How Can I update the SentOn date in a .msg file located in local folder on my machine? Can this be done using python, VBA or any other tool?

MailItem.SentOn property is read-only in OOM. There are a few MSG file parsers for Python, but I have only seen libraries that can read MSG files, but not create/update existing ones. You can read/create/update MSG files using Extended MAPI, but it is accessible in C++ or Delphi only.
If using Redemption (I am its author) is an option, it allows to open existing MSG files and update any of their properties. In VBA:
  set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
  set Msg = Session.GetMessageFromMsgFile("c:\Temp\test.msg")
  Msg.SentOn = Now
  Msg.Save

